# Smallest linux distribution for PPTP VPN server (poptop)?

Tags: distribution-choice, vpn, vmware, pptp

I want to run [Poptop](http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/), an Open Source PPTP Server for Linux.

I need the smallest possible GNU/Linux distribution which I can install in VMware Workstation 8 and which will be able to support this software.

Which Linux distribution should I choose/download?

A GUI would also be nice because I'm the regular windows-user/programmer/whatever I can call myself. (but is not required, I am comfortable with command lines)

I would also be very thankful if someone could post step-by-step installation and configuration instructions for this specific setup.

Comment: How about an easy way?  [Grab a minimal Debian 6.0](http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/#debian6.0) VMWare image and go for something along the lines of this [a little dated but Debian-specific HOWTO](http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/debian-howto.phtml) (I'm not sure (i.e. I've never tried any `pptpd`) if this works, though, just sharing a thought.)

Comment: How important is the small footprint requirement? As a functional distro, it doesn't get much smaller than [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/), at 50MB. There's no package for Poptop though, so you'd have to compile it from source. I have no idea how easy or hard that is (and the instructions on the site are [very outdated](http://poptop.sourceforge.net/dox/source-howto.html)), so I don't know if this would work for you. But it's an option.

Comment: @sr_ I did install the debian squeeze with gnome and pptpd and configured it, people can connect and ping the server (192.168.1.8) but cannot ping my router (192.168.1.1) not my PC (192.168.1.6) and don't have internet access... after playing with the cinfig file I still didn't fix it, this is my 'final' output for the config file: http://ideone.com/x8OWB